# Multiple Adapters, one object map

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an application which gets gets both *transactional* and *reference* data from a singular REST backend but I would like to cache the reference data into `localStorage` while keeping the default RESTAdapter semantics for the transactional data.

I'm using beta-2 of Ember-Data and wondering if it would be possible to use a combination of RESTAdaptor and a somewhat modified version of Ryan Florance's local_storage adapter (which apparently has now been updated for the new Ember-Data API). The change I'm considering is rather than having the localStorage as the storage end point it would act only as a caching mid-point (hopefully that makes sense).

I'm very new to ember-data and I noticed that `TRANSITION.md` that everyone's working off of talks about 'per type adapters'. That sounds encouraging but then the example declaration of an adapter is simply:

> App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.MyRESTAdapter;

Is there any significance to the `ApplicationAdapter`? Is this just the default? Then if I designate the a *type* of `ReferenceType` to have a custom adapter:

```
App.ReferenceTypeAdapter = DS.CacheAdapter.extend({
   // ...
});
```

Would this work? Will I still be able establish model relationships between my transactional data (managed by MyRESTAdapter) and reference data (managed by the CacheAdapter)?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct.  `ApplicationAdapter` is the application wide default adapter.  You can then override it on a "per type" basis by naming your new adapter appropriately.  I would think that relationships would still work, but I have not tried anything like this, so I can't speak from experience.